# Программное нажатие на кнопку из расширения обозревателя

Tags: javascript, jquery, chrome-extension

Делаю расширение для [сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/). Согласно логике необходимо добавить ссылку, при нажатие (пользователем) на которую, мне необходимо инициировать (программно) нажатие ссылки на сайте.

Конкретно, добавляю ссылку в панель инструментов. При клике на ссылку, необходимо открыть меню добавления комментария под вопросом за счет клика на ссылке «добавить комментарий».

```
function processAddingAssociationLink() {
    $("#question .post-menu").append("<a id='associate-link' class=''>" + associateHelpText + "</a>");
    $("#associate-link").click(function() {
        $(".question .js-add-link").trigger("click");
        $(".question .comment-form textarea").text(associationTag + " ");
        $(".question .comment-form input").val(addAssociationHelpText);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

Вызов `$(".question .js-add-link").trigger("click");` не создает нажатия, хотя если выполнять этот код в консоли Хрома, все работает, как надо. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить?

Если выполнить код (`$(".question .js-add-link").trigger("click");`) в консоли, а затем нажать на созданную мной кнопку, то необходимые поля обновляются (то есть часть обработчика отрабатывает).

**Обновление**

Решение может быть [такое](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2490876/564240):

```
var event; 

if (document.createEvent) {
    event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    event.initEvent("click", true, true);
} else {
    event = document.createEventObject();
    event.eventType = "click";
}

event.eventName = "click";

var element = $(".question .js-add-link")[0];
if (document.createEvent) {
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
} else {
    element.fireEvent("on" + event.eventType, event);
}
```

Но не до конца понятно, почему оно работает, а стандартный вызов – нет.

Comment: Я, возможно, сейчас глупость скажу, но когда вы вызываете `$(".question .js-add-link").trigger("click");`, нужно указывать номер элемента: `$(".question .js-add-link")[0].trigger("click");` и так со всеми вызовами элементов по классу.

Comment: @Mae вы сами-то пробовали так сделать?

Comment: @PavelMayorov Сейчас я не работаю с javascript, я помню, что была такая проблема, и знаю, что иногда опытные люди забывают основы, поэтому и пишу, что вспомнилось.

Comment: @Mae в данном случае вам вспомнилось магическое движение бубна которое вы не помните что означает.

Comment: @pavel вообще-то помню... Почему магическое? Я действительно не знаю, поможет здесь это или нет, но вы обо мне какого-то странного мнения. Вы недовольны конкретным моментом или просто плохой день? Прошу прощения за эту странную дискуссию, Nicolas, но мне бы хотелось, чтобы Павел уточнил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут есть две проблемы.

Основная проблема заключается в том, что метод trigger в jquery выполняет только те обработчики, которые были назначены элементу в том же самом jquery. Ну еще иногда выполняет другие обработчики - но не всегда. А у вас в расширении загружен другой инстанс jquery.

Вторая проблема, content script выполняется в изолированном окружении и в принципе не имеет доступа к объектам страницы, поэтому обычный ответ в таком случае *"зачем вы добавили на страницу вторую jquery?"* не применим.

---

Для того, чтобы вызвать обработчик независимо от того кто его зарегистрировал - следует использовать [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent).

Альтернативный вариант - можно внедрить на страницу обычный скрипт через инъекцию тэга `<script>`. Для этого понадобится файл с внедряемым скриптом добавить в список [web accessable resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) расширения.

Comment: [Все-таки trigger выполняет все навешанные обработчики, не только jquery](https://jsfiddle.net/228fcexd/2/)

Comment: @Grundy там в коде есть костыль для событий, навешанных через `"onXXX=..."`. Но в изолированном окружении даже это работать не будет.

Comment: @Grundy Подскажите, почему тогда trigger не отрабатывает?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, _Вторая проблема, content script выполняется в изолированном окружении и в принципе не имеет доступа к объектам страницы_

Comment: @Grundy вот реализация: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event/trigger.js. Можете убедиться, что dispatchEvent тут даже не пытается вызваться.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ага, но при этом в том же фидле, который я скинул - по trigger - вызываются _все_ навешанные обработчики, и через jquery, и через разметку, и через addEventListener. По крайней мере в хроме

Comment: @Grundy странно...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, там в итоге сделано просто :) [elem\[type\]()](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event/trigger.js#L139) - в нашем случае будет: `input.click()`